# Does LibreOffice Calc calculation time out or have any limits?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc, timeout

I have a relatively large spreadsheet (2300 rows, out to column EL) and lately the auto calculate has been unreliable. I would have to click on a cell I was sure was incorrect, hit F9 and see its value update. The formula is correct and nothing changes, but it requires a manual prompt to recalculate even though automatic calculation seems to be enabled.

Does the calculate method have any limits that I am bumping into or is this a bug?

**Edit:**

As requested, one example cell whose function did not update correctly is:

```
=CY$6-SUM(CY$9:CY2349)
```

There is a suggestion some functions do not update correctly even on small spreadsheets, I am curious what functions these are.

Comment: What is the formula of a cell where the problem occurs?  Also mention any values and formulas that the cell references.  Certain formulas sometimes have trouble updating automatically, even in small spreadsheets.